# Get two tables data on a single MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am not so much experienced with MVC in ASP.NET. Currently working on Visual Studio 2015 Community on a demo MVC project.

I am having difficulties having two tables combined in a view.

Following are two tables of concern from few tables.

**I want to show data from both the tables at the same time in a single View(HTML Page).**

**TABLE - COMPLAIN**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[COMPLAIN](
[JOBSHEET_NO] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[COMPANY_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MODEL_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[IMEI_SRNO] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[BATTERY_WITH_MOBILE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[MEMORYCARD_WITH_MOBILE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[FAULT_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
[CUSTOMER_NAME] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[CUSTOMER_MOBILE] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ASSIGNED_TO_TECHNICIAN] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[REMARKS] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
[CREATE_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[IN_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[USER_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[ESTIMATE_AMOUNT] [float] NULL,
[ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[OUT_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[JOBSHEET_COMPLETE_STATUS] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[NARRATION] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_COMPLAIN] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JOBSHEET_NO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF,    ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

**TABLE - REPAIRING**

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[REPAIRING](
[JOBSHEET_NO] [int] NOT NULL,
[IN_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[CREATE_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[ESTIMATE_AMOUNT] [float] NULL,
[ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[START_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[END_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[OUT_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NULL,
[USER_ID] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[NARRATION] [nvarchar](500) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_REPAIRING] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [JOBSHEET_NO] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REPAIRING]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT    [FK_REPAIRING_COMPLAIN] FOREIGN KEY([JOBSHEET_NO])
REFERENCES [dbo].[COMPLAIN] ([JOBSHEET_NO])
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[REPAIRING] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_REPAIRING_COMPLAIN]
GO
```

I am having FK relationship between those two tables.

**I would also like to know if data from both the tables can be available without any FK relationship.**

Following are my models.
**COMPLAIN.cs**

```
namespace WebMSM.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public partial class COMPLAIN
{
    [Key]
    [ReadOnly(true)]
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("JOBSHEET NO")]
    public int JOBSHEET_NO { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("COMPANY NAME")]
    public string COMPANY_NAME { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("MODEL NAME")]
    public string MODEL_NAME { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("IMEI")]
    public string IMEI_SRNO { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("BATTERY WITH MOBILE")]
    public string BATTERY_WITH_MOBILE { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("MEMORY CARD WITH MOBILE")]
    public string MEMORYCARD_WITH_MOBILE { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("FAULT")]
    public int FAULT_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("CUSTOMER NAME")]
    public string CUSTOMER_NAME { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("CUSTOMER MOBILE")]
    public string CUSTOMER_MOBILE { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("TECHNICIAN")]
    public string ASSIGNED_TO_TECHNICIAN { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("REMARKS")]
    public string REMARKS { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATE_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> IN_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("USER ID")]
    public string USER_ID { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("ESTIMATE AMOUNT")]
    public Nullable<double> ESTIMATE_AMOUNT { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("ESTIMATE AMOUNT OK?")]
    public string ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OUT_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("STATUS")]
    public string JOBSHEET_COMPLETE_STATUS { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("NARRATION")]
    public string NARRATION { get; set; }

    public virtual MASTER_FAULT MASTER_FAULT { get; set; }
    public virtual REPAIRING REPAIRING { get; set; }
}
}
```

**REPAIRING.cs**

```
namespace WebMSM.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
public partial class REPAIRING
{
    [Required]
    [DisplayName("JOBSHEET NO")]
    public int JOBSHEET_NO { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> IN_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CREATE_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("ESTIMATE AMOUNT")]
    public Nullable<double> ESTIMATE_AMOUNT { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DisplayName("ESTIMATE AMOUNT OK?")]
    public string ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("START REPAIR TIME")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> START_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("END REPAIR TIME")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> END_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("OUT TIME")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> OUT_TIMESTAMP { get; set; }
    public string USER_ID { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("NARRATION")]
    public string NARRATION { get; set; }

    public virtual COMPLAIN COMPLAIN { get; set; }
}
}
```

**Now I have created a RepairingController which displays list of COMPLAINs on its index View. 
From that View, by Clicking 'Edit' link, I would like to go to Edit view in which data from both the tables about that record should be available.**

Following is **RepairingController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebMSM.Models;

namespace WebMSM.Controllers
{
public class RepairingController : Controller
{
    private MSMContext db = new MSMContext();

    // GET: Repairing
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(db.COMPLAINs.ToList());
    }

    // GET: Repairing/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        REPAIRING rEPAIRING = db.REPAIRINGs.Find(id);
        if (rEPAIRING == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(rEPAIRING);
    }

    // GET: Repairing/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: Repairing/Create
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "JOBSHEET_NO,IN_TIMESTAMP,CREATE_TIMESTAMP,LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP,ESTIMATE_AMOUNT,ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER,START_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP,END_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP,OUT_TIMESTAMP,USER_ID,NARRATION")] REPAIRING rEPAIRING)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.REPAIRINGs.Add(rEPAIRING);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(rEPAIRING);
    }

    // GET: Repairing/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        var lstOKNOTOK = new List<SelectListItem>()
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text="OK",Value="OK" },
            new SelectListItem {Text="NOT_OK",Value="NOT_OK" },
        };

        ViewBag.ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER = lstOKNOTOK;
        REPAIRING rEPAIRING = db.REPAIRINGs.Find(id);
        if (rEPAIRING == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(rEPAIRING);
    }

    // POST: Repairing/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "JOBSHEET_NO,IN_TIMESTAMP,CREATE_TIMESTAMP,LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP,ESTIMATE_AMOUNT,ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER,START_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP,END_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP,OUT_TIMESTAMP,USER_ID,NARRATION")] REPAIRING rEPAIRING)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Entry(rEPAIRING).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(rEPAIRING);
    }

    // GET: Repairing/Delete/5
    public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        REPAIRING rEPAIRING = db.REPAIRINGs.Find(id);
        if (rEPAIRING == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(rEPAIRING);
    }

    // POST: Repairing/Delete/5
    [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
    {
        REPAIRING rEPAIRING = db.REPAIRINGs.Find(id);
        db.REPAIRINGs.Remove(rEPAIRING);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }
}
```

}

Following is **Edit.cshtml** View For **RepairingController.cs**

```
@model WebMSM.Models.REPAIRING

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>REPAIRING</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.JOBSHEET_NO)

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.JOBSHEET_NO, htmlAttributes: new {  @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.JOBSHEET_NO,  new { @class =  "form-control" ,@readonly="readonly"} )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.JOBSHEET_NO, "", new {  @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.IN_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new {  @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.IN_TIMESTAMP, new {  htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IN_TIMESTAMP, "", new  { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CREATE_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CREATE_TIMESTAMP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CREATE_TIMESTAMP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LAST_EDIT_TIMESTAMP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ESTIMATE_AMOUNT, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ESTIMATE_AMOUNT, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ESTIMATE_AMOUNT, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER,ViewBag.ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" } )
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ESTIMATE_AMOUNT_OK_FROM_CUSTOMER, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.START_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.START_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.START_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.END_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.END_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.END_REPAIRING_TIMESTAMP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.OUT_TIMESTAMP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.OUT_TIMESTAMP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.OUT_TIMESTAMP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    @*<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.USER_ID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.USER_ID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.USER_ID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>*@

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NARRATION, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-4" })
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NARRATION, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NARRATION, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-5 col-md-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting us to wade through all this - 95% of which is irrelevant to the question. Refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Got it sir. Will be careful.

Comment: Sir I know how to ask a minimal question but its possible that someone might ask for code that is related to question, so i posted more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new view model class which has properties to represent data from both the tables

```
public class ComplaintDetailsVm
{
  public Int JobSheetNo {set;get;}
  public string CompanyName {set;get;}
  public string CustomerName {set;get;}

  public Decimal EsitmatedAmount {set;get;}
  //Add other properties AS NEEDED
}
```

And use that for your view.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
   var vm = new ComplaintDetailsVm();
   var r =db.REPAIRINGs.Find(id);
   if(r!=null)
   {
     vm.JobSheetNo = r.JOBSHEET_NO;
     vm.CustomerName= r.CUSTOMER_NAME;
     //Map other properties here as needed
     if(r.REPAIRING !=null)
     {
        vm.EstimatedAmount = r.ESTIMATED_AMOUNT;
        //Map other properties here as needed
     }    
   }
   return View(vm);
}
```

And your view

```
@model ComplantDetailsVm
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.CompanyName)
  @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.EstimatedAmount)
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.JobSheetNo)
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

So when user posts the form, we need to read the data from our viewmodel object and use that for saving

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(ComplantDetailVm model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    var e=db.COMPLAINs.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.JOBSHEET_NO==model.JobSheetNo);
    if(e!=null)
    {
       // Update the property values
      e.CompanyName = model.CompanyName;
      //Map other properties also 
       db.Entry(e).State = EntityState.Modified;
       db.SaveChanges();
       //to do : Redirect to Success message page.
    }
  }
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Great, will check and let you know.Thanks.

Comment: i changed the line to `var e = db.ComplainDetailsVms.FirstOrDefault(s => s.JOBSHEET_NO == model.JOBSHEET_NO);`. But now it says `The entity type ComplainDetailsVm is not part of the model for the current context.`